# Remapping ; and : in Vim breaks it

Tags: vim

I've just discovered that some people tend to remap their `:` to `;` in Vim (since `;` is only used for search, and `:` is used all the time, not having to press `Shift` all the time is great).

EDIT (forgot to show what I did):

```
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;
```

I tried it, and I love it. However, it does come with a price. It kind of breaks my configs, eg:

```
map <leader>G mG:Git!
```

Commands like the one seen above no longer work.

So my question is, to those who remap their semicolons, what is the remedy for this? Should I just remap `:` and `;` on system level via xmodmap instead?

**Decision:**
Ultimately, I've decided to remap colon and semicolon at system level, for consistency purposes.

Comment: Seems like you actually want to map `;` to `:` rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nnoremap <leader>G mG:Git!
```

allows you to use : in its original meaning.

(edit) Obligatory reference in [LVHW.](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html#nonrecursive-mapping)

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot about that. I feel so silly (been up all night again, my brain is broken)...